# Using Watir Webdriver and WYSIWYG

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

Using Watir Webdriver I am able to detect that a WYSIWYG ckeditor exists, however any attempt to `send_keys` to it outputs a blank string?

I am able to run the test above with the ckeditor without issues:

```
require "watir-webdriver"
b = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
b.goto "http://ckeditor.com/demo"
b.frame(:title => 'Rich text editor, editor1, press ALT 0 for help.').send_keys "hello world"
```

I am however, having an issue running this code for my own test:

```
b.frame(:title, "Rich text editor, currentItem.contentText, press ALT 0 for help.").exists?
=> true

b.frame(:title, "Rich text editor, currentItem.contentText, press ALT 0 for help.").send_keys 'text'
=>""
```

Nothing is rendered to WYSIWYG. 
Other frames on webpage allow me to edit text fields. Any thoughts?

Comment: I would prefer not to use the execute_script method because it invalidates my testing.

Comment: Why would using execute_script method invalidate your testing? Unless you're actually developing your own WYSIWYG editor, you're not testing the editor, but rather it can be used to add content to your application, which is achieved through the execute_script method?

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking sending keys to a whole frame is a bad idea.

In my own experience with the FCKEditor, I've only gotten it to work if I find the *specific element* that can respond to the .send_keys method.

Here's an example of something that works for me (I am guessing that my first frame element reference is going to be equivalent to the frame element you're hitting using the "title" tag):

```
@browser.frame(:id, "body___Frame").td(:id, "xEditingArea").frame(:index=>0).send_keys "your text here"
```